# How to create a subdomain

Tags: nginx

I want to create a sub-domain in NginX with same files in windows
For example:

> www.helloworldtest.com
>   www.vodafone.helloworldtest.com

Please give me a knowledge of conf file as I am totally new to NginX.

Comment: https://albertogrespan.com/blog/running-multiple-domains-or-subdomains-in-nginx-with-server-blocks/

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new server block with the appropriate server_name:

```
server {
    server_name www.helloworldtest.com
    location / {
        # server some files
    }
}
server {
    server_name www.vodafone.helloworldtest.com
    location / {
        # server some files
    }
}
```

Or add the subdomain to the server_names of an existing server block (if you want the same response):

```
server {
    server_name www.helloworldtest.com www.vodafone.helloworldtest.com
    location / {
        # server some files
    }
}
```